# Signing S3 URL's using AWS Cloudfront with Ruby

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-cloudfront

I was analysing the URL signing for longer years using AWS Cloudfront for S3 bucket URL's. have anyone worked on this? and can anyone had succeeded on this and any reference steps to do this?